# Reverse a string at every nth occurance in it

Tags: c++, c, string, logic

I have a string `str[]="ABCDEFGHI"` and say n=3. I need to implement `reversestring(arr,n)` logic for any input string, for any value of n. In this case, my output has to be `str = "CBAFEDIHG"`

If my `str[]="PQRSTUVWXYZ"`, for n=4, my output has to be `str = "SRQPWVUTXYZ"`. In such cases,you can ignore reversing the last occurrence, as there are less than 4 letters.

Could the similar logic be generalised for `input[]="this is a simple test", output[]="sith si a elpmis tset"` without using any nth occurrence condition using function overloading in c++.

Comment: Yes it's possible, and in C++ it's actually very easy. You might want to read about [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) and [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: the words that you are looking for are "lexicographic permutations" now you can use Google to do this :)

Comment: Is 'o/p' for output a common abbreviation? It took me a good 10 seconds to figure out what was meant (despite the intent and the rest of the sentence being clear).

Comment: @Elliot Robinson I have never seen it before but is kind of growing on me.

Comment: Why do you want to use overloading? (depending on the reason, it may be or not be possible to use it)

Comment: @ElliotRobinson I have never seen it. Just to be clear, "o/p" seems to mean "output".

Comment: @ElliotRobinson, Edited the Q to clear all confused guys.Now you all should be happy persons.

Comment: @Bala Please see the answer I posted. It actually uses `std::reverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are dealing with C-style strings, if you want to reverse every n characters you can simply do something along the lines of the following:

```
//Iterators
int x, y;
char str[] = "ABCDEFGHI";
int n = 3;
int strLen = strlen(str);

//Assuming C99+ for variable length arrays...
char newStr[strLen + 1];


if (strLen % n != 0) {
    printf("For this simple example the length of str must be a multiple of n\n");
    return 0;
}

for (x = 0; x < strLen; x += n) {
    for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        newStr[x + y] = str[x + (n - y) - 1];
    }
}

//Ensure string is terminated properly
newStr[strLen] = 0;

printf("Converted %s to %s\n", str, newStr);

return 0;
```

In terms of generalising this, the second example you give involves reversing words, rather than blocks of `n` characters, so you therefore need a different approaching of splitting the string at separate words and reversing those chunks, which is a different problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using only one library function, `std::reverse`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "ABCDEFGHI";
    std::string s1_output = "CBAFEDIHG";
    std::string s2 = "PQRSTUVWXYZ";
    std::string s2_output = "SRQPWVUTXYZ";
    int N1 = 3;
    int N2 = 4;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s1.size() / N1; i++)
        std::reverse(s1.begin() + (i * N1), s1.begin() + (i * N1 + N1));
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (s1 == s1_output) << std::endl; // true
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s2.size() / N2; i++)
        std::reverse(s2.begin() + (i * N2), s2.begin() + (i * N2 + N2));
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (s2 == s2_output) << std::endl; // true
}
```

Your second example is different from your first example, because you're operating on individual words, and not a range. It is also different because you don't ignore chunks that are smaller than `N`.

As suggested in the comments, you can use `std::istringstream` and use the extraction operator, to extract "chunks" inbetween whitespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "this is a simple test";
    std::string s1_output = "siht si a elpmis tset"; // you made a typo

    std::istringstream iss(s1);

    std::string chunk;
    std::string output = "";
    while (iss >> chunk) {
        std::reverse(chunk.begin(), chunk.end());
        output += chunk + " ";
    }
    output.erase(output.size() - 1, output.size()); // chop off remaining space
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (output == s1_output); // true
}
```